# what's the equivalent of the python zip function in dataflow?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm using the python apache_beam version of dataflow. I have about 300 files with an array of 4 million entries each. The whole thing is about 5Gb, stored on a gs bucket.

I can easily produce a PCollection of the arrays `{x_1, ... x_n}` by reading each file, but the operation I now need to perform is like the python zip function: I want a PCollection ranging from 0 to n-1, where each element `i` contains the array of all the `x_i` across the files. I tried `yield`ing `(i, element)` for each element and then running GroupByKey, but that is much too slow and inefficient (it won't run at all locally because of memory constraints, and it took 24 hours on the cloud, whereas I'm sure I can at least load all of the dataset if I want).

How do I restructure the pipeline to do this cleanly?

Comment: Actually, I think the approach you took is the correct one, but it should have run in _way_ faster than 24 hours - do you have a job ID that I can inspect and see what went wrong?

Comment: I'm currently running it with the full dataset of 176 * 208 * 176 * 278 elements, still not done after two days of machine time.

that's the job id @jkff 2016-10-28_08_36_06-9231369576702658658

Comment: It seems like the job was started only 2 hours ago, rather than 2 days - are you referring to the total time spent on all workers, rather than the elapsed time? I looked at the job and I don't see anything pathological: the data has already been grouped by key and your job is reading through the grouped data, but processing it at a slow rate - could it be that one of your user-code DoFn's applied to the result of the GBK is itself slow? Can you try running it on a much smaller dataset using the in-memory runner, and optimize the code locally?

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the total worker time. I can run it both locally and on the cloud in a few minutes, if I limit the arrays to be 64 items long, instead of 6M. What should I look into in order to make it faster?

As an example of this, I just ran that as 2016-10-28_12_03_15-14751323132943042673 and it completed in about 10 mins real time.

Comment: I only have access to the Dataflow service logs, but I do not have access to your data or your code per se. I suggest you look at your DoFn's and use one of the Python profiling tools (https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) to measure them and estimate how long they would take on your dataset (e.g. if there's 24 hours of work just to invoke your DoFn's on the data, Dataflow can do this in parallel, but can't reduce the total amount of work). It may be best to write a microbenchmark for your DoFn's without even using the Dataflow API at all, and profile that.

Comment: Perhaps you can post a somewhat obfuscated version of your code, to see if there's any algorithmic complexity issues? In the 64-item pipeline you posted, the amount of data is extremely small, but there are still obviously heavy computations going on, since it's actually busy running your DoFn's the whole 10 minutes.

Comment: well if you want you can check the actual code here, it's not a secret at all:

https://github.com/Enucatl/machine-learning-aging-brains

Comment: I have two candidate slow functions here:

https://github.com/Enucatl/machine-learning-aging-brains/blob/master/agingbrains/voxel_fit.py

maybe the scikit-learn GaussianRegressor and KernelDensity are too much? Should I abandon this altogether?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126935/discussion-between-enucatl-and-jkff).

Comment: Hey, I looked at https://github.com/Enucatl/machine-learning-aging-brains/blob/master/agingbrains/io.py and read_records returns just 1 record. It's better implemented as a DoFn. In general when making a FileBasedSource you need to use the range_tracker properly; e.g. see how AvroIO is implemented https://github.com/apache/incubator-beam/blob/python-sdk/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/avroio.py, and use https://github.com/apache/incubator-beam/blob/python-sdk/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/source_test_utils.py to unit-test - feel free to reach out to dataflow-feedback@google.com for more help.

Comment: thanks for the additional input, I took inspiration from the AvroIO module for writing my own source, but I really couldn't get my head around the range_tracker without any additional guidance. It looked like I could live without, I may come back to that or ask for more help about that in the next days.

Comment: Note that using range_tracker is not optional - if the code works without that, it is by accident (I'd even say that we should have detected this and automatically failed the pipeline). The documentation indeed leaves much to be improved :-/ In case you emit exactly 1 record per file, you should just call range_tracker.try_claim(0) and test the return value before outputting any records (since the record is logically at offset 0 in the file), and you should also pass splittable=False to the super() constructor (to disable splitting into offset ranges since your format can't read ranges).

Comment: If the issue was resolved, could you post an answer, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jkff pointed out in the above comment, the code is indeed correct and the procedure is the recommended way of programming a tensorflow algorithm. The DoFn applied to each element was the bottleneck.